# Build WatchOS Apps: Develop and Design

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am trying to run some sample code from the book Build WatchOS: Develop and Design.  The following segment of code returns two errors:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(){
        if animating {
            spinnerImage.stopAnimating()
            animating = false
            animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToStopped())
        } else {
            spinnerImage.startAnimating()
            animating = true
            animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToGoing())
        }

    }
```

Both errors occur in the calls to animateWithDuration() and indicate that there is a type conflict.  Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In a hurry?

Instead of calling `animateWithDuration` like so:

```
animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToStopped())
```

you'd like to give it your `updateButtonToStopped` function as a parameter like so:

```
animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToStopped)
```

Notice that the () after `updateButtonToStopped` is gone.

And the same goes for `updateButtonToGoing` of course :)

### Why?

If you look at the documentation for `animateWithDuration`, (which you can see the Swift 3 version of [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628239-animate)) you can see that the signature looks like this:

```
func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Void)
```

The `animations` is the interesting part here.

```
() -> Void
```

means that `animations` takes a function, which must contain no parameters and which returns `Void`.

In your case you call it like so:

```
animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToStopped())
```

But...when you use `updateButtonToStopped()`, what you are actually saying is, "call `updateButtonToStopped()` and use *the output* of that for the `animations` parameter". This is not what the compiler expects, it expects, as we just saw, a function, taking no parameters and returning `Void`.

So when you say:

```
animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: updateButtonToStopped)
```

Without the parentheses it means that you do not invoke `updateButtonToStopped`, you just pass it to `animate` as a parameter.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks!  You have cleared this up for me.  I appreciate your excellent explanation of what is going on.  I just tested the changes, and they work perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help you solve the mystery :) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted :)